# Dyno specific environment variable on heroku possible?

Tags: heroku, environment-variables

Is it possible to have different values for the same environment variable for each of the dyno on heroku?

For example: 
web.1: 100
web.2: 200

Answer (score 1):

A little-know fact: the environment variable `PS1` (yes, the shell prompt) used to hold values such as "web.1", "worker.2", etc. It was later changed to `PS`, and as per [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/293?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter) it is now called `DYNO`.

Answer (score 0):

No, however you can create a UUID on app initialization, which would be unique across each of the dynos, and can be used for logging and whatnot.

Comment: UUID is too large for me in this case. My value needs to fit in one byte. Not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was lookign for a solution to the same problem and found something in the sidekiq issue tracker that may help: [Setting ENV variables at startup](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/374)

Quoting contributor betegeuse:

> Apparently not. Any way just prepend the command with env and it will work:
>
> `worker: env ANY_ENV=foo any_command`